# how to pass null = null in the where clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery select statement where in some cases, the where clauses show `null = null`

In the case of this statement:

```
select * from `db.ds.table1` t1
join `db.ds.table2` t2
on t1.first_name = t2.first_name
and t1.last_name = t2.last_name
```

as you can see, this would appear to be looking for people, however, in some cases, I have businesses in the tables.  In those cases, `first_name` is used, and `last_name` is null.

this means I have a `null = null` scenerio, and fails join.

How do I tell bigquery to allow `null = null`, without having to put coalesce statements all over the place?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
select * from `db.ds.table1` t1
join `db.ds.table2` t2
on t1.first_name = t2.first_name
and ifnull(t1.last_name, '') = ifnull(t2.last_name, '')
```

obviously ifnull is equivalent of coalesce so not sure if this is what you can accept as you mention you wanted not to use coalesce for some reason

Comment: This might be OK, but in the (possibly rare) case that empty string should be recorded as either `last_name`, this query could give false results.

Comment: hope OP will be able to come with the appropriate value if `''` will conflict with possible existing values for last name - if such edge cases exist

Comment: well, I didn't want to have to put that on every field, but I guess there's no way around that.

Comment: Just to clarify - Do you mean in your real use case you have multiple such fields like last name?

Answer (score 3):

Make the last name optional, and allow both last names being `NULL` as valid:

```
SELECT *
FROM `db.ds.table1` t1
INNER JOIN `db.ds.table2` t2
    ON t1.first_name = t2.first_name AND
       (t1.last_name = t2.last_name OR (t1.last_name IS NULL AND t2.last_name IS NULL));
```

We could also try to write a query using `COALESCE`, but it isn't really clear what value should be used in place of a `NULL` last name.